# How to fix two table joins to remove duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables, and I have joined them to output exactly what I want, but now I want to remove the duplicate rows so that the MISTI col isn't showing repeated records. I have tried using `Distinct`, but I keep running into problems. Here is my SQL query that works exactly how I like it to minus the duplicate records. Here is also a snapshot of my output

[image: OUTPUT]

```
SELECT  g.entity                                      AS MISTI,
        t.cur_state                                   AS STATE,
        ROUND(((SYSDATE - t.cur_state_dttm) * 24), 2) AS HRS,
        te.technician
FROM Entity_Grp_Lst    g
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        trk_id_def        t
            ON g.facility = t.facility
               AND g.grp_type = t.grp_type
               AND g.entity = t.entity
               AND g.grp_type = '720'
    LEFT JOIN
        trk_id_technician te
            ON t.facility = te.facility
               AND t.grp_type = te.grp_type
               AND t.trk_id = te.trk_id
               AND cur_state_dttm = te.state_in_dttm
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD', 'NM', 'TERM', 'NULL', 'IDLE', 'YER', 'PENG', 'LBQU', 'LBQS', 'I07', '20')
        AND Entity_Grp_type = '085'
        AND g.ENTITY_GRP = 'MET'
ORDER BY g.entity,
        t.cur_state_DTTM DESC;
```

Comment: When you eliminate `MISTI` column, how do want the rest of the columns be summarized? For instance, rows 8-15 has the same value for `MISTI`, what do you want to do with the `TECHNICIAN` column? It would be easier for someone to help, if you could post how do you expect your final result be.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1):

the distinct it doesn't working because you have a column which is different from the others and is the 'technician' column, as you can see in the screenshot you sent the 'technician' or the 'hrs' it's different,so even if you use distinct that doesn't work because basically the entire row it's different if there are some different values, i recommend to remove the 'technician' column from the select:

```
Select DISTINCT
   g.entity as MISTI,
   t.cur_state      as STATE,
   ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS
```

and try again with the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not duplicates records, others fields value are changing.
If you need to keep distincts values on MISTI you can do this :

```
SELECT  MISTI
        ,STATE
        ,HRS
        ,technician
FROM    (
        SELECT  g.entity                                      AS MISTI,
                t.cur_state                                   AS STATE,
                ROUND(((SYSDATE - t.cur_state_dttm) * 24), 2) AS HRS,
                te.technician
                ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by g.entity order by te.technician desc)  as rn
        FROM Entity_Grp_Lst    g
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                trk_id_def        t
                    ON g.facility = t.facility
                       AND g.grp_type = t.grp_type
                       AND g.entity = t.entity
                       AND g.grp_type = '720'
            LEFT JOIN
                trk_id_technician te
                    ON t.facility = te.facility
                       AND t.grp_type = te.grp_type
                       AND t.trk_id = te.trk_id
                       AND cur_state_dttm = te.state_in_dttm
        WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD', 'NM', 'TERM', 'NULL', 'IDLE', 'YER', 'PENG', 'LBQU', 'LBQS', 'I07', '20')
                AND Entity_Grp_type = '085'
                AND g.ENTITY_GRP = 'MET'
        )q
WHERE   q.rn = 1
ORDER   BY MISTI,HRS DESC
```

This ranks lines on MISTI and i only keep the first line, you can change the order by clause to match your need.